# Run/See Nunit4 in Rider

Tags: nunit, rider

I tried to upgrade Nunit 3->4.
Now my IDE cannot see any tests.

I have investigated proj files, delved through nuget packages/versions and looked at [the documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/release-notes/Nunit4.0-MigrationGuide.html).
The tests can be run through the cli `dotnet test -v=normal`

My IDE is [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) on a Mac m2.

Comment: That's a known issue

Comment: @mu88 Any source? to know where to poll for when it work? (I haven't found it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue, you have to use Rider 2023.3. I filed an issue at JetBrains and the answer was:

> Rider 2023.2 does not support NUnit 4. Please update to Rider 2023.3 where it is fully supported.